# Where can I read Shakta Agamas online in English?

Tags: agamas, resource, shaktism

I'm searching for Shakta Agamas online in English. Can anybody provide me the relevant links or PDFs to read these Agamas?

P.S. So far, I could only find Kularnavara Tantra. You can read it [here](https://holybooks-lichtenbergpress.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/Kularnava-Tantra.pdf).

Comment: I have read nearly all the tantras online and Kularnavara tantra also..i remember i was searching for the Shakta Agamas in the past but did not found that..if you get please share.